# Python very slow to start 100 threads

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to make use of threads in python.

I need each thread to call the same function (which use a while(True) loop) with a different argument.

So, in this exemple, I create 81 objects (Trader), and append them all to a list (traders). 
I then use the concurrent.futures library to start my threads.

'exec_strats' is a function that uses a while(True) loop.

```
for ma_range in range(10, 200, 10):
    for overhead in range(1, 10, 1):
        trader = Trader(id=str(ma_range)+':'+str(overhead))
        header.append(trader.id)
        args = [trader, ma_range, overhead]
        trader.add_strat(exec_strat_sec, args)
        traders.append(trader)

start = time.time()

result = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(traders)).map(exec_strats, traders)

end = time.time()
print("Time for "+str(len(traders))+" threads to start : " + str(end - start) + " seconds")
```

To start 9 threads, it takes about 3 seconds. To start 100 threads, about 5 minutes.

Could anyone explain to me if there is a problem with my code, or if I just shouldn't use python to that kind of multithreading and why ?

---

### EDIT 1

Thanks for the quick replies,

To clarify, I need only 1 worker per task, but I need all the workers working concurrently, and not 1 after the other. The task execute a fairly simple calculation that needs to be repeted forever.

Comment: Why are you bothering with a "thread pool" if you're always sizing it to be large enough to assign each task to a unique worker.

Comment: GIL. Python only runs 1 thread at a time. I personally have not tried anything with 100 plus threads. Also you should set a fixed number of threads in your thread pool. The tasks will be assigned individually when a thread is available. I don't know what you want your threads to be doing but you should probably look at multiprocessing if your program is not IO bound.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I edited my post to add some more information. @JasonChia I thought the ThreadPoolExecutor already made use of multiple processors. Isn't it the case ?

Comment: Just for the records: just throwing "more" threads at a problem isn't necessarily doing anything good. You always always always have to understand what you are doing, and why you are doing it. More threads only help when the hardware has the capacity, or when the threads spent most of the time waiting for IO traffic to happen. Adding more threads to a CPU intensive workload simply slows everything down for example.

Comment: In my case, I require a large amount of threads. Each of them will execute an numerical average on some data stored in a LinkedList. More data is added to the LinkedList every second. Each thread will have to execute an average of different size. For exmeple, the first thread will do the average of the last 100 data points, the 2nd the average of the last 50 points, etc. Doing the calculation in paralel is crucial to avoid lagging.

Comment: Why not use a stream and then perform computations on the incoming stream? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average. Threads are unecessary for your problem I think. Primary reason why threading won't do well is because of Python depending on GIL https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock. This means that the CPU only runs one thread at a time. And thusly is not really parallel processing unlike in Java or C. Multiprocessing is the only way to truly achieve parallel processing.

Comment: It wouldn't take too much more effort to make a working example in your question. Although it probably wouldn't change the responses, at least we can give more specific answers.